# Validation of sql query in a textarea form in Angular 2

Tags: sql, validation, angular

One of the requirements in my project is to validate an input sql query string on frondend in Angular 2 before sending it to the server. Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: For which database (Oracle, MySql, PostgresQL, ...)? Actually I think this is a question about a library that does that, which is a kind of question that is discouraged on SO. If it is about doing it yourself, it's too broad for SO.

Comment: hope this might help you https://github.com/forward/sql-parser

Comment: it's for MS SQL